# wp_add_inline_script not adding when script_loader_tag filtered

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-localize-script, google-analytics

I'm trying to add the new GA4 code to an existing site, and there seems to be some conflict / ordering issue between `script_loader_tag` filters and `wp_add_inline_script`. My `functions.php` looks thusly:

```
...
// Enqueue scripts
function cwr_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('cwr-google-analytics', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
            . '/js/ga.js', array(), '1.0.3');
        wp_add_inline_script('cwr-google-analytics', "ga('create', "
            . "'" . CWR_GAUA_ID . "', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');");


        wp_enqueue_script('cwr-google-gtag', "https://www.googletagmanager.com"
            . "/gtag/js?id=" . CWR_GA4_ID, array(), null);
        wp_add_inline_script('cwr-google-gtag', "window.dataLayer = "
            . "window.dataLayer || [];"
            . "function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js',"
            . "new Date()); gtag('config', '" . CWR_GA4_ID . "');");
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cwr_enqueue_scripts');

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'cwr_gtag_async', 10, 3); // problem causer
function cwr_gtag_async($tag, $handle, $src) {
        if ($handle === 'cwr-google-gtag') {
                $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" id="cwr-google-gtag-js"'
                    . 'src="' . esc_url($src) . '" async></script>';
        }

        return $tag;
}
?>
```

As is, it outputs three lines, and never adds the "after" script to `cwr-google-gtag`:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" id="cwr-google-gtag-js" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<my_id>" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/js/ga.js?ver=1.0.3" id="cwr-google-analytics-js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="cwr-google-analytics-js-after">
ga('create', '<my_id>', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
...
```

If I comment out the `script_loader_tag` filter, then I get my extra code added, but obviously lose the `async` attribute:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/vantage-child/js/ga.js?ver=1.0.3" id="cwr-google-analytics-js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="cwr-google-analytics-js-after">
ga('create', '<my_id>', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-GCBJ73QR90" id="cwr-google-gtag-js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="cwr-google-gtag-js-after">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js',new Date()); gtag('config', '<my_id>');
</script>
...
```

Any ideas what's wrong here? Or, is there a better canonical way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the markup that is filtered by `script_loader_tag` includes the inline scripts. So when you filter it and replace *all* the HTML tag for a particular script, your filter is removing those inline script tags. If you print out the original value of `$tag` from within your filter you will see this.

You can look at the source of [`WP_Scripts::do_item()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/do_item/) to see how the inline scripts are prepended and appended. With your approach you would need to replicate all that logic. The better approach is to just use `str_replace` to replace part of the script tag with an amended part, like this:

```
if ( $handle === 'cwr-google-gtag' ) {
    $tag = str_replace(
        'id="cwr-google-gtag-js"',
        'id="cwr-google-gtag-js" async',
        $tag
    );

    return $tag;
}
```

That will add `async` after the correct script tag's ID attribute.

All that being said, your approach is not going to work. If `ga.js` is loaded asynchronously, then the subsequent inline script tag is going to run before `ga.js` has loaded, which will cause an error because `ga()` has not been defined by the time this runs:

```
ga('create', '<my_id>', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');
```

See this example from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) for loading Google Analytics asynchronously:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

For this to work you need an inline script *before* the analytics script is loaded, and that script needs to include a line that defines `ga()` if it has not been defined yet.

Lastly, you should not be hosting Google Analytics in your theme. As advised [by Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en):

> While it's possible to download the JavaScript file (gtag.js) to
> examine it, storing or serving the JavaScript file locally is not
> recommended.
>
> Referencing the JavaScript file from Google's servers (i.e.,
> https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js) ensures that you get access
> to new features and product updates as they become available, giving
> you the most accurate data in your reports.

You should consult Google's documentation to make sure Google Tag Manager doesn't also need to be loaded a particular way, when adding it asynchronously.

Comment: A few things: your answer is perfect, except somewhere between the internal WP process and the output on the page, the single and double quotes get reversed, so you if you could edit your answer to reverse them, that would be great! 2) I'm not loading ga asynchronously, just gtag. For gtag example code, this is what google gives,`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<code>"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '<code>');
</script>`

Comment: Lastly, while it appears I'm locally storing the analytics code, that's not actually what I'm doing. The ga.js referenced is `(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');`